# MYSQL: Only retrieve users with specific data field

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `Order`, `Payment`, and `User`.

I'm trying to find *only* the users who used a particular payment method (Cash) and who did not use any other form of payment.

The simple query I built looks like this:

```
select 
user.id,
user.fname,
user.lname,
user.email
from `order` as o
inner join payments on o.id = payments.order_id
inner join user on o.user_id = user.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = 6
and o.order_status != "Cancelled"
and payments.payment_method = "Cash"
group by user.id
```

However, this will return users if they used Cash as a payment method at least once, during the time frame. How do I limit to ONLY cash and no other forms of payment?

Should I have multiple subqueries for each form of payment then compare each return vs other to eliminate more and more users?

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - I appreciate your suggestion, however, I deal with the hand that's dealt to me.

Comment: Is this a one time query or will it be done often?

Comment: @2bigpigs I don't really know. I'm running a report and it will be later determined if it will make it into permanent reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a not in user.id that use other methods

```
  select 
  user.id,
  user.fname,
  user.lname,
  user.email
  from `order` as o
  inner join payments on o.id = payments.order_id
  inner join user on o.user_id = user.id
  where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
  and o.store_id = 6
  and o.order_status != "Cancelled"
  and payments.payment_method = "Cash"
  and user.id not in (select distinct o.user_id 
                      from `order`  
                      inner join  payments on o.id = payments.order_id 
                      where payments.payment_method <> "Cash" )
  group by user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add not in condition in where to check for payments from same users who has payment method other than cash to exclude them.
Some thing like:-

```
select 
user.id,
user.fname,
user.lname,
user.email
from `order` as o
inner join payments on o.id = payments.order_id
inner join user on o.user_id = user.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = 6
and o.order_status != "Cancelled"
and payments.payment_method = "Cash"
and not in (select 1 from payments pym where pym.orderid = o.id and o.id = user.id and pym.payment_method <> 'Cash')
group by user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [not exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) subquery to rule out users with any other payment types in that time frame:

```
select 
user.id,
user.fname,
user.lname,
user.email
from `order` as o
inner join payments on o.id = payments.order_id
inner join user on o.user_id = user.id
where o.orderplaced_ts > "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
and o.store_id = 6
and o.order_status != "Cancelled"
and payments.payment_method = "Cash"
and not exists (select 1
                from `order` as o2
                inner join payments p2 on o2.id = p2.order_id
                where o2.orderplaced_ts > "2016-08-01 00:00:00"
                and o2.store_id = 6
                and o2.order_status != "Cancelled"
                and p2.payment_method != "Cash"
                and o2.user_id=user.id)
group by user.id, user.fname, user.lname,user.email
```

The advantage of not exists subquery is that it does not have to pull the results from the subquery, it just checks if the subquery would return any records.